# Trying to graph time on x axis using d3

Tags: grails, d3.js

I am working in a Grails environment to get some data from a csv file to out put in d3. The timestamp data is in the format of "Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute:Seconds AM/PM". My data for my y axis passes in perfectly, but it just graphs out my x-axis as a single data point. How do I get the data so that it's just the Hour:Minute and graph it out

Here is my code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
            .showDistX(true)    
            .showDistY(true)
            .transitionDuration(350)
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())


chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
  return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>'
})

chart.xAxis.axisLabel('X Axis label').tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0,d))})

chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Time').tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))

chart.scatter.onlyCircles(false)

var myData = generateData(4)
d3.select('#chart svg')
  .datum(myData)
  .call(chart)

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update)

return chart
 })


function generateData(groups) { 
var data = []


for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
data.push({
  key: 'Group ' + i,
  values: []
})



<g:each in="${list}" var="money">      

data[i].values.push({
    x:  ${money.open}       

  , y: ${money.high}
  , size: 20  
  })
</g:each>
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you verify that you don't have any syntax errors in this code example, and possibly clean it up? I was going to suggest an edit to improve the clarity, but I can't figure out where parts of your code are supposed to end (possibly missing some closing braces in your `generateData` function). End of line semi-colons aren't required in JavaScript, but, in a language that doesn't care about white-space, they go a long way in making code more readable, and maintainable.

Comment: Can you try format method on your date object 'money.open.format("hh:mm")'